# submit order and redirect to an individual platform

Tags: python, sql, django, redirect, relational-database

i am trying to develop a django webapp .i want the user to be able to submit other and get redirected to the user's platform where the user sees all his orders . i want a system where the user can make orders and get redirected to a page where will see all his orders

client form:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}  

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %} 



{% if user.is_authenticated %}




<div class="container" style="width: 50rem;">
    <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 mt-5">
        <div class="jumbotron"> 
             <!--<h3 id="form-title">Job Specification </h3>-->
            <h3 class="display-4" style="text-align: center;">Service Request</h3>
            <p  id="form-title" style="color: #343a40; text-align: center;">Please provide us with the following information</p>
            <hr class="my-4">
       
       

            <form action="{% url 'clients:add_item' %}"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        {{ form.job_name|as_crispy_field }}
                       
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        {{ form.text_description|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                </div>
             
               
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        {{ form.location|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        {{ form.address|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                
           
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <!--{{ form.phone|as_crispy_field }}-->
                    <input style="height: 2.5rem;margin: 0 0 8px 0;  width: 100%; text-align: center; position: relative; " type="text" name="phone" value="{{ user.details.phone }}"   readonly><br>
       
                         </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        
                        <input style="height: 2.5rem;margin: 0 0 8px 0;  width: 100%; text-align: center; position: relative; " type="text" name="email" value="{{user.email}}"  placeholder=" email "  readonly><br>
       
                    </div>
                </div>
               
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        {{ form.status|as_crispy_field }}
                    </div>
                   <div class="col-md-6" style="height: 2rem;">
                       <!---{{ form.customer|as_crispy_field }}-->

                       <input style="height: 2.5rem;margin: 0 0 8px 0;  width: 100%; text-align: center; position: relative; top: 30px;" type="text" name="customer" value="{{ user.username}}"  placeholder="username" readonly><br>
                   
                    </div>-->
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-6">
                        
                    <input style="height: 2.5rem;margin: 0 0 8px 0;  width: 100%; text-align: center; position: relative; " type="text" name="id" value="{{ user.details.id }}"  placeholder=" id "  readonly><br>
   
                </div>
                <h2>
                                   <!-- Your template -->

      
                </h2>
          <!--<div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
                    <input class="btn login_btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
            
                </div>-->
                <button role="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Submit</button>
   
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


{{ form.errors }}
{% else %}


<div class="container" style="width: 20rem; background-color: #6e1a52; margin-top: 70px; height: 20rem;" >
    <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 mt-5" >
        <!--<div class="jumbotron"> 
             <h3 id="form-title" style="text-align: center;">Please login to enable you request the service you want</h3>-->
            <h3 class="display-44" style="text-align: center; font-size: 22px; margin-top: 50px; color: #343a40;">request service</h3>
            <p id="form-title" >Please login to enable you request the service you want</p>
           
                <a href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}"
                 style="font-size: 24px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none;" >Login</a>
          
           <!-- <a action="{% url 'profession:add_item' %}" role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</a>-->
        </div>
    </div>
 

{% endif %}
```

view file for  client view:

```
@login_required
def insert_ClientJob(request):

   
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        form = ClientJobForms(request.POST)
        user_id=request.POST.get('id') 
     
        if form.is_valid():
            product = form.save(commit=False)
            #customer = ClientJob.objects.create(customer=product)
       
            #product.customer =customer
           
            product.save()
           
            messages.success(request ,"successful")
            return redirect('profession:user',user_id)
         
    else:
        form = ClientJobForms()
       
    return render(request ,'job_request.html' ,{'form': form})     


url file client url:

om django.urls import path
from .views import *
from .import views

app_name = 'clients'


urlpatterns = [

path('add_item/', views.insert_ClientJob ,name='add_item'),

]
```

model file client model:
from django.db import models

```
# Create your models here.


class ClientJob(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
            ('Pending', 'Pending'),
            #('On-going', 'On-going'),
            ('Completed', 'Completed'),
            )
    
    customer = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Customer', null=True,blank=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL,related_name='client')
   
      
    job_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique =False)
    text_description = models.CharField(max_length=150,null=True) 
    location = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Area' ,on_delete =models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique =False)
    phone =models.CharField(max_length=15,unique =False)
    email = models.EmailField(unique = False) 
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS,default='Pending')
    


    def __str__(self):       
        return self.job_name
      
   
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Client Job"
```

form file client form:

```
from django.db.models import fields
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .models import *





class ClientJobForms(ModelForm): 
 
  class Meta:
    model = ClientJob
    fields = ['job_name','text_description','location','address','phone','email','status','customer']
    #fields ="__all__"

  

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ClientJobForms, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
    self.fields['location'].empty_label ='Your location'
```

admin file client admin:

```
    list_display = ('id','job_name','text_description','location','address','phone','email','date_created','status','customer')

admin.site.register(ClientJob ,ClientJobAdmin)



accounts model:



class Area(models.Model):
    area_code = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.location

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Area"



class Customer(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,blank=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL,related_name='details')
   address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
   phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
   date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

   def __str__(self):
      return str(self.user)
```

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: customer
Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.